# Jquery popup overlay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, popup, containers

I just saw the `jQuery Popup Overlay` demo on github, [Here](https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay)

downloaded the file query.popupoverlay.js

and added it to my project. and added this to my home page just to make sure it's working:

The button:

```
  <a class="initialism basic_open btn btn-success" href="#basic">Basic</a>
```

The container:

```
    <!-- Basic -->

<div id="basic" class="well" style="max-width:44em;">
    <h4>Basic example</h4>
    <p>Try to change the width and height of browser window, or to rotate your device, and also try to navigate with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.</p>
    <p>You can close the dialog by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or by clicking on the background outside the content area, or by clicking on the Close button.</p>
    <button class="basic_close fade_open btn btn-default">Next example</button>
    <button class="basic_close btn btn-default">Close</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.popup.defaults.pagecontainer = '.container';
        $('#my_popup').popup();

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#basic').popup();
    });
</script>



    </div>
```

I use google chrome, by the way.

Comment: r u getting any error in console

Comment: no i am not getting

Comment: make sure you have added jquery plugin. No issues found by running your code

Comment: I added it at the top of the page: jquery.popupoverlay.js.

Comment: Not only jquery.popupoverlay.js, you have to add jquery plugin as well

Comment: It's a huge project and I'm a part of it, i have jquery library already in there .. is it different than  the plugin? can u please give me a link

Comment: @AneeshRS where can i download the plugin from?

Comment: Go through the answer. I have added it in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the plugin you should add jquery plugin in the script. The undesigned popup box is just due to the lack of css, that i havent added

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#basic').popup();
    $('#basic1').popup();
    $('#basic2').popup();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>


<a class="initialism basic_open btn btn-success" href="#basic">Basic</a>
<div id="basic" class="well" style="max-width:44em;">
    <h4>Basic example</h4>
    <p>Try to change the width and height of browser window, or to rotate your device, and also try to navigate with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.</p>
    <p>You can close the dialog by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or by clicking on the background outside the content area, or by clicking on the Close button.</p>
    <button class="basic_close fade_open btn btn-default">Next example</button>
    <button class="basic_close btn btn-default">Close</button>
</div>



<a class="initialism basic1_open btn btn-success" href="#basic1">Basic1</a>
<div id="basic1" class="well" style="max-width:44em;">
    <h4>Basic 1 example</h4>
    <p>Try to change the width and height of browser window, or to rotate your device, and also try to navigate with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.</p>
    <p>You can close the dialog by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or by clicking on the background outside the content area, or by clicking on the Close button.</p>
    <button class="basic1_close fade_open btn btn-default">Next example</button>
    <button class="basic1_close btn btn-default">Close</button>
</div>

<a class="initialism basic2_open btn btn-success" href="#basic2">Basic2</a>
<div id="basic2" class="well" style="max-width:44em;">
    <h4>Basic 2 example</h4>
    <p>Try to change the width and height of browser window, or to rotate your device, and also try to navigate with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.</p>
    <p>You can close the dialog by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or by clicking on the background outside the content area, or by clicking on the Close button.</p>
    <button class="basic2_close fade_open btn btn-default">Next example</button>
    <button class="basic2_close btn btn-default">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: which one is the plugin? is it jquery.min.js ?

Comment: both are needed. jquery.min.js for jquery and jquery.popupoverlay.js for popup

Comment: the second one is the same as the one from github right? which i already added to my project

Comment: ya.is there any problem?

Comment: when i click on the button it just takes me to the container at the bottom of the page, the container was supposed to poup

Comment: please copy and paste the code, that will work. I dont understand what you mean by not working. It is the same code that you have asked. And also check the console for any errors

Comment: oh thanks when i added your script it works :) it means my code cannot access the file i downloaded, is there a way where i can download the two scripts you just put?

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js , https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js just click the links and save it by CTRL + S

Comment: If it fixes your issue, please upvote and mark it as answer

Comment: is there a way where i can change the id to be other than #basic? or should i put them in an another div? cuz i'm going to retrieve objects from db i want each object to have its own id and contianer

Comment: You can add any number of popups.i have updated my answer with 3 popups.Updation requires in button class name, div id and close button class

Comment: I'm actually trying to add it in a for loop and i want each one to have its own ID

Comment: No worries, go through the loop and assign new ids to the div and class to the button

Comment: if i change the name and not make it **basic**. i will have to change the query right? cause it's based on this name. i just changes the id and href and made it become the objects' ids and the page got messed up

Comment: like, when i made the href and id become the object i'm retrieveing from the database all the containers are displayed now as a list with the objects. they are not popups anymore

Comment: i changed the script to be    $('#<%=myobject.ID.ToString()%>').popup(); but now when i click the button which is supposed to show the popup it doesn't show anything

Comment: you have to change both html and js to achieve it

Comment: I just did. the script is inside my loop that retrieves from the database so i just change it. is it wrong to use **<%** "Dataretrieved **%>** inside JS?

Comment: when i paste it in console, it gives me this error:  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=myobject.ID.ToString()%>
    at Function.ga.error (1.11.3.js?1.6.0:2)